Issues with ICL7660 ICs from eBay - Overheating and Failure
I recently purchased several cheap ICL7660 ICs from eBay to use in an OpAmp circuit. Unfortunately, I've encountered issues with these components, specifically overheating and subsequent failure.
Here is a picture of the IC I'm using:

And here is a picture of the circuit I built to get a negative voltage. Pin 6 is not connected to ground because the supply voltage is greater than 3.5 V (as stated in the datasheet):

I'm using 9V supply voltage for this circuit. Initially, the circuit operates as intended, producing both +9 V and -9 V outputs. However, the ICL7660 ICs occasionally become extremely hot. After overheating, the ICs appear to be damaged, losing their ability to produce a negative voltage. I already lost 4 of 10 ICs this way.
I'm not sure what the problem is. Could the overheating and subsequent failure of the ICL7660 ICs be due to purchasing counterfeit or low-quality components from eBay?
Are there alternative or higher quality versions of the ICL7660 IC that I should consider for future projects?

RL 10 kOhm maximum, and 10 V max ... (LV open). Are you sure you don't pass 10 V?

I'm using 9V power supply for effects pedals. It should not exceed 10V. I just did another test: I had the power supply connected to my circuit, everything was working as expected. Then I disconnected the positive wire and reconnected it again - after that the IC overheated and broke again.

why not put a gap pad or a heatsink ?

Because, once the 7660 starts overheating, I looses it's ability to generate a negative voltage

When I measure the resistance between the output of the 7660 and ground, while the power supply is not connected, I read around 130kOhm. Although it is not a stable reading. I just got one Opamp connected (inverting mixer with two input channels and 100k resistor each) Could the load resistance be the problem?

It's possible they are bad. Your photo shows an ICL7660S which is a different part (some improved characteristics, including a 12V rating) from the ICL7660 and ICL7660A. The logo and markings are close, but not exactly the same as known-good parts (eg. lcsc). The difference is not definitive IMO. There are a lot of clones of the 7660 around, and many of them rated for 9V to 10.5V (absolute maximum). Most of them are actually used at +/-5V so they may suit most applications.
What would be definitive and easy to test is if the part fails the output resistance specification that is on the original datasheet.
However!! Note this in the datasheet:

In some applications, an external Schottky diode from VOUT to CAP- is
needed to ensure latchup free operation (see Do’s and Dont’s section
on page 8).

and then


If the input voltage is higher than 5V and it has a rise rate more
than 2V/µs, an external Schottky diode from VOUT to CAP- is needed to
prevent latchup (triggered by forward biasing Q4’s body diode) by
keeping the output (pin 5) from going more positive than CAP- (pin 4).

User should ensure that the output (pin 5) does not go more positive than GND (pin 3). Device latch-up will occur under these
conditions. To provide additional protection, a 1N914 or similar diode
placed in parallel with C2 will prevent the device from latching up
under these conditions, when the load on VOUT creates a path to pull
up VOUT before the IC is active (anode pin 5, cathode pin 3).



You are experiencing classic symptoms of latchup-triggered failure.
(some transient causes latchup and then your power supply provides the energy to overheat and destroy the chip)

A similar warning appears in the ICL7660 datasheet, but omits the Schottky diode recommendation.

User should insure that the output (pin 5) does not go more positive
than GND (pin 3). Device latch up will occur under these conditions. A
1N914 or similar diode placed in parallel with C2 will prevent the
device from latching up under these conditions. (Anode pin 5, Cathode
pin 3).

Bottom line (more or less): I suspect the parts are just fine but have a new vulnerability introduced by way of the 'S' improvements.
From your comment above:

Then I disconnected the positive wire and reconnected it again -
after that the IC overheated and broke again.

This could well cause the high (>2V/us) dv/dt that the datasheet warns against for the 'S' version of the chip.
Personally, I think I'd add both diodes (probably in the form of a single BAT54A) so the circuit could use either variation of the chip.

Wow thanks a lot for this detailed answer! This is really helpful. I will try what you suggested and report back.

Since you bought from ebay, it's most likely either fake parts or parts which didn't pass testing.  Throw them out and buy from any reputable supplier.

There are improved versions of the xxx7660, for instance the ICL7660A from Renesas has a max supply voltage of 12 V and 45 mA output capability. The xxx7662 has higher voltage, up to 20 V, and Microchip makes a replacement for those, the TC962EPA, that will do 80 mA

Thanks a lot for your answer. I might try a xxx7662 or a  TC962EPA
